# c# - using file.encrypt to save some persistent info locally?

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a program that needs to save some user-unique information on each user's machine (I query the user for it upon first use).  In my first draft of the program I simply saved that info in a text file (in a sub-folder of the program folder).  But it is open text, and I'd like to change it so that it is not so easy to read.

After reading some articles in MSDN I thought that using File.Encrypt and File.Decrypt would do the job.  I didn't want to hash the text, because I need to retrieve it and use it in my program in its open form. (As you can guess I have not worked with encryption before - which is also why I am not anxious to use something more complex - but will do so if it is my only alternative).

Here's my code, which is not working.  I'd appreciate any feedback about what I am doing wrong...

```
if (File.Exists(@"subfolder\a.txt"))
        {
            File.Decrypt(@"subfolder\a.txt");
            string unique = File.ReadAllText(@"subfolder\a.txt");
            File.Encrypt(@"subfolder\a.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            string unique =
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your
            unique text ...", "Enter your unique text", "");
            File.WriteAllText(@"creds\u.txt", username);
            File.Encrypt(@"creds\u.txt");
        }
```

Thanks.

A relative newbie....

Comment: *"Here's my code, which is not working"*, you never told us ***how*** it is not working. Do you get a error message? Does the program crash? What? Also `File.Decrypt` and `File.Encrpt` don't work like that, you don't need to deencrypt it to read the file. Windows does it for you automatically when you open the file as the user who encrypted it, you just treat it as a normal unencrypted file.

Comment: You can use [application and user settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx). User settings get saved on the windows AppData folder but anyway if you would like to make it a bit harder for users to view what you saved you can just encode it and decode it in your app to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first think about your methdology here.

```
If (the file exists) {
    Decrypt the file
    Read the contents
    Encrypt it again
} else {
    Enter text
    Save as a different file name than above
    Encrypt the file
}
```

When you decrypting the file, you are trying to decrypt the file on the disk leaving it unencrypted.
You then read the content, and encrypt it again.

This approach assumes that you are decrypting the file to the disk, then reading the contents, however this is not the correct usage.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301070

You mentioned you don't want to hash the data, but assuming that you will be using a suitable complex salt and key, you can store these in the program for use in a proven hashing algorithm.

Somebody could potentially retrieve these by decompiling the IL code, but it's still more secure than decrypting on the disk.

Have a read of the following article which will explain a few factors of secure hashing you might find useful.
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Part of the issue you might have with `File.Encrypt` is that it is not universally supported across windows platforms, which to my mind makes it close to useless.

Fundamentally, if you're intending to decrypt the data for use in your program, I doubt your main concern is somebody cracking a network and getting access to company secrets, more keeping people from messing with configuration data or similar.
Hashes with salt using keys stored in code is perfectly fine for this, but will not satisfy any serious security concerns in an enterprise grade application.

This article will walk your through the process. Instead of asking for a password, you can store the cipher as a string in your program if you would like, although if you included a login prompt for your program, you could use the example code pretty much unchanged.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx